# Persistent increase of a python list size after every code execution

Tags: python, list, persistence

My code starts with an empty list:

```
l = []
```

Let us say I want to append 5 elements to my list every time I run my code:

```
l += [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
print(l) . # reuslt is l = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

After the code execution, this information is lost.
I want to know how can my list keep growing by five zeros every time I run my code again.

```
first run >>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
second run >>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
third run >>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
.
.
.
```

Comment: Store it in a file and reread it. JSON will do nicely.

Comment: Surely because you are using `+=` it does increment exactly like you want, unless you redeclare `l` as empty every time? Are you asking how to persist the data between runs?

Comment: yes, Chris. I want to know how to persist the previous values of the list between runs.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: does writing to a file and reopen it still the way to go for what I want to achieve?

Comment: @Y.Henni I have added an answer providing an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist the data between runs. One way of doing this is by using the `pickle` module, which I will demonstrate here as it is very simple. An alternative would be using `JSON`. These methods can save (or serialise) a Python data object. This is different from just writing text to a text file.

```
import pickle

my_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# Save my_list
file = open("save.txt", "wb") # "wb" means write binary (as opposed to plain text)
pickle.dump(my_list, file)
file.close()

# Close and restart your Python session

file = open("save.txt", "rb") # "rb" means read binary
new_list = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

print(new_list) # -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Edit**: You stated that you want the additions to the list to happen automatically every time the code is run. You could achieve this by appending after loading and then saving again.

```
import pickle

# Create an empty list
my_list = []

# Try to load the existing list in a try block in case the file does not exist:
try:
    file = open("save.txt", "rb") # "rb" means read binary
    loaded_list = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    my_list += loaded_list
except (OSError, IOError):
    print("File does not exist")

# Append to the list as you want
my_list += [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# Save the list again
file = open("save.txt", "wb")
pickle.dump(my_list, file)
file.close()

print(my_list) # This will get bigger every time the script in run
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. But I wanted the list to grow with zeros every time I execute the code, the output of your script is a list with the same number of zeros.

Comment: @Y.Henni So do you want it to add the five zeros every time it is run automatically? I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Y.Henni I have added an extra part to the answer for this.

Comment: if you run the edited script it will always raise the exception error ! maybe you missed something in your code ?

Comment: @Y.Henni It works for me in Python 3.6. The first time it prints "File does not exist" but then after that it gets longer with each run. What version are you using and which line is giving the error?

Comment: My bad I had a typo in my code. Chris it works like a charm, I have signaled yours as the answer to my question. Looking forward to more discussions with you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

All of your program variables are, by definition, local to the scope of your program.  When you exit the program, the operating system gets to reclaim the space.  To make data persist after program end, you need to store it somewhere else, such as in a file -- a resource outside the volatile existence of the Python run-time system.

I trust that you can look up file operations.

Comment: I will look into this. I know I can open files for write and read with python. However, I am wondering how the data flow of the code will look like for such an operation.

Comment: That's also covered in the file tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

After execution you will lose all data in your ram. So there will be no way of keeping your list in ram after the process has ended. You'll have to write your list to a file and read that file every time you excecute your code.

This may help:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python